# eliminate changes in the work area (git)

Tags: git

I need to remove the `octofamily/dos.gif` and `octofamily/one.txt` files in the work area. How do I do it? I'm using git 1.9.

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
new file:   blue_octocat.txt
new file:   octofamily/baby_octocat.txt
new file:   octofamily/momma_octocat
new file:   red_octocat.txt
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
octofamily/dos.gif
octofamily/uno.txt
```

This doesn't work.

```
git checkout -- octofamily/dos.gif
```

Comment: git checkout -- octofamily/dos.gif  not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are untracked, you can just delete them.

```
rm octofamily/dos.gif
rm octofamily/uno.txt
```

Please note that, since Git isn't tracking them, **they will be gone forever.**